# My CSS code is not running please check

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#f1ff36;
    font-family:verdana;
}

.center{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

a{
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:2px solid transparent;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:24px;
    color:#262626;
}

a:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:-2px;
    left:-2px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    background:transparent;
    border:2px solid transparent;
}

a:hover:before{
    animation:animate 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border-top-color:#262626;
        border-right-color:transparent;
        border-bottom-color:transparent;
        border-left-color:transparent;

    }
    50%{
        width:100%;
        height:0;
        border-top-color:#262626;
        border-right-color:#262626;
        border-bottom-color:transparent;
        border-left-color:transparent;

    }
    100%{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        border-top-color:#262626;
        border-right-color:#262626;
        border-bottom-color:transparent;
        border-left-color:transparent;

    }
}

a:hover:after{
    animation:animate2 1s linear forwards;
    animation-delay:1s;
}

@keyframes animate2{
    0%{
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border-top-color:transparent;
        border-right-color:transparent;
        border-bottom-color:transparent;
        border-left-color:#262626;

    }
    50%{
        width:0;
        height:100%;
        border-top-color:transparent;
        border-right-color:transparent;
        border-bottom-color:#262626;
        border-left-color:#262626;

    }
    100%{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        border-top-color:transparent;
        border-right-color:transparent;
        border-bottom-color:#262626;
        border-left-color:#262626;

    }
}
```

`animate2` is not working at all tell me the error which is occuring in this code.

In this code as you can see there are two animations first animation is working fine but the second animation ie `animate2` is not working at all. Tell me at which point I am making the mistake I am really confused and frustrated trying and trying to run this code but to no avail.

Comment: show some html code please?

Comment: your `after` has no content so won't show

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add empty content block a:after
Take a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/jornare/pen/opojVo)

```
a:before, a:after {
```